# how to correct config buildroot/uCLibc to get the spawn function

Tags: spawn, buildroot, uclibc

I try to use buildroot (2014.02) to generate ucLibc(0.9.33.2) Toolchain for mips, but it would not generate the spawn.h and other spawn related files on output/build/uclibc-0.9.33.2/ nor output/host folder, 
I confirmed that the UCLIBC_HAS_ADVANCED_REALTIME and UCLIBC_HAS_REALTIME are all set to 'y' in uCLibc Config.in, I also found the spawn.h on ./output/build/host-m4-1.4.17, but they never get in to the toolchain. Could someone help to prompt how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

spawn.h routines are only available in the not yet released uClibc master
development branch. You must choose uClibc snapshot version in the Buildroot
configuration.

Thank Baruch's help